# Connect manually with sails.io.js

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-extension, sails.js

I'm trying to use sails.io.js in a chrome extension.

I'm setting manually the url of my sails server with the line :

```
io.sails.url = "http://localhost:1337";
```

But I would like to get the url from the chrome local storage (to save the url not directly in the code). But the problem is, as said [here](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails.io.js/issues/12#issuecomment-53440042):

> You get 1 clock tick after the import before the socket attempts to
>   connect.

So if I get the URL from the chrome local storage with :

```
storage.get('url', function(result){
    var url = result.url;
    io.sails.url = url ;
});
```

It's too late! The options must be set just after the sails.io.js code..

So I was thinking about disabling autoConnect with :

```
io.sails.autoConnect = false;
```

(As said [there](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails.io.js/blob/master/example/index.html))

But now my question is : How can I can connect manually with io.sails ?

I've tried io.sails.connect(), did not work. Any ideas ?

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's yours to customize but if you want to get away with minimal amount of changes to sails.io.js then you could

- change setTimeout to `io.sails.doit = function() {`
- throw away the `io.sails.autoConnect` check
- call `io.sails.doit(..)` when you're ready

Also, if you want to pass something over during the handshake you can add `{'query':'param='+value}` as second argument to `io.connect(io.sails.url);`
It is then available in sails app's config/sockets.js through `socket.handshake.query.param`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I put the full sails.io.js file in a function, in order to load it later, and defined "io" globally. It works like a charm :)

Comment: @stt  Hi, I know this issue was at long time, Do you can give me an example of your solving? Thanks!